# Backtransform for confidence intervals

Tags: r

I am currently trying to back-transform occupancy models to get Confidence Intervals (CI).
However, when back-transforming models in the first place so I can after calculate CI, I have to use `LinearComb()` function. It is here where I get stuck.

Model:

```
m47=occu(~tree cover ~habitat+native, data=uf02)
```

Back-transform:

```
mm=backTransform(linearComb(m47, coefficients = c(1, 0, 0), type ="state"))
```

Variables:

- tree cover: categorical (1-5)
- habitat: categorical (habitat type name)
- native: numeric (0-100%)

Can somebody explain me what are those coefficients about (`c(1, 0, 0)`)?

The error that appears is

> Error in .local(obj, coefficients, ...) :
>   (coefficients) == length(obj@estimates) is not TRUE

I can't find anywhere which coefficients I must use...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question refers to a lot of functions that are in packages, not in base R. Can you please edit your question to add what packages you are using? Otherwise, no one will know how to help you.

Comment: At first glance it seems as though you might want to change your values in `coefficients`.

Comment: yes but how? what is the criteria?